# scapy did not send packets

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

i try to create scapy tools to test sniffing, this is my code :

```
def scan(ip):
    arp_req = sc.ARP(pdst=ip)
    bc = sc.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_req_bc = bc/arp_req
    answer = sc.srp(arp_req_bc, timeout=1, verbose=True)[0]
    print("IP\t\t\tMAC Address\n-----------------------")
    for element in answer:
        print(element[1].psrc + "\t\t" + element[1].hwsrc)

scan("192.168.43.1/24")
```

the output is :

```
    "Sniffing and sending packets is not available at layer 2: "
RuntimeError: Sniffing and sending packets is not available at layer 2: winpcap is not installed. You may use conf.L3socket orconf.L3socket6 to access layer 3
```

Comment: It says `winpcap is not installed.` Have you tried installing winpcap?

Answer (score 1):

Download and Install WinPcap from this link:
https://www.winpcap.org/install/
and Run your program again.

Note: You have to close and restart Terminal Window,  if You are using Command Line Terminal to run your program.

Answer (score 0):

for using scapy module in windows, first you need to install npcap or wincap.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the layer 3 sniffer using:
**conf.L3Socket= L3RawSocket;**
this would help you in the sniffing process..since a sniffer needs a raw socket to implement its functionality..